# Send dynamic variable with Paypal button

Tags: angular, firebase, paypal

My website is using Angular with Firebase Realtime.

I am trying to pass the [uid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56twS.png) of a user when they click on my website [button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKvqo.png) and it will take them to a paypal donate page for them to complete the transaction.

The button will trigger the function onNavigate() and open a new tab to the [paypal page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpUzs.png).

```
onNavigate() {
    window.open(this.project.paypalProjectURL, '_blank');    
  }
```

The paybal button currently has a [paypal advanced variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMnJ9.png) that is linked to a webhook and will then send the data to firebase under [payments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xT04y.png).

Is there a way where I can send dynamic data (uid) this way? As every user will have a unique uid and it needs to be attached to every paypal transaction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In advanced variables, add `custom=someuid`

This [is documented](https://developer.paypal.com/api/nvp-soap/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx-websitestandard-htmlvariables/#link-paymenttransactionvariables)